# getting wrong number argument error using Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, pdfkit

Hi i am getting the following errors while using wicked_pdf gem in Rails3.

> error:

```
ArgumentError in UsersController#download_pdf

wrong number of arguments (0 for 1)
Rails.root: C:/Site/generate4

Application Trace | Framework Trace | Full Trace
app/controllers/users_controller.rb:6:in `download_pdf'
```

After clicking on download pdf link the following error is coming.

> error-2:

```
RuntimeError in UsersController#download_pdf

Error: Failed to execute:
["C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe", "--encoding", "UTF-8", "file://C:/DOCUME~1/SUBHRA~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/wicked_pdf20150527-1192-1qf0ac.html", "C:/DOCUME~1/SUBHRA~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/wicked_pdf_generated_file20150527-1192-fijfxt.pdf"]
Error: PDF could not be generated!
 Command Error: Loading pages (1/6)
[>                                                           ] 0%
[======>                                                     ] 10%
Error: Failed loading page file://c/DOCUME~1/SUBHRA~1/LOCALS~1/Temp/wicked_pdf20150527-1192-1qf0ac.html (sometimes it will work just to ignore this error with --load-error-handling ignore)
Exit with code 1 due to network error: ContentNotFoundError
```

Please check my code below.

> users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def index

    end
    def download_pdf
        pdf=WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string(
         render_to_string pdf: "test.pdf", template: "users/test.html.erb", encoding: "UTF-8")

        @save_path = 'C:\Site\download_pdf.pdf'
    end
end
```

> users/test.html.erb:

```
<h1>Hello rails</h1>
```

> wicked_pdf.rb:

```
WickedPdf.config = {
  #:wkhtmltopdf => '/usr/local/bin/wkhtmltopdf',
  #:layout => "pdf.html",
  :exe_path => 'C:/Program Files/wkhtmltopdf/bin/wkhtmltopdf.exe'
}
```

> Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.19'

gem 'sqlite3'
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'wicked_pdf'
```

My requirement is convert HTML to PDF using Rails 3.Please help me to resolve this error and successfully get the PDF file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming, you are trying to download the pdf file.

see the code below:

```
#users_controller.rb:
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def download_pdf
    pdf = render_to_string(pdf: "test.pdf", template:  "users/test.html.erb", encoding: "UTF-8")
    send_data pdf
  end
end

# Gemfile

source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.19'

gem 'sqlite3'
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'

gem 'wicked_pdf', :github => 'mileszs/wicked_pdf', :branch => 'master'
```

Please check if it works.

Comment: @ sufinsha : But after editing your code this error had gone but when i am trying to generate pdf file it is throwing the error which has posted in question as error-2.

Comment: @ sufinsha : I updated your latest code again the same error as error-2 in post.Let me to make you confirm i am using windows system.

Comment: @rajat_474 Can you please mention ruby version, rails version and wickedpdf version?

Comment: @ sufinsha : Ruby version 1.9.3,Rails version 3.2.19 and wicked_pdf version i have not mentioned simple added gem 'wicked_pdf'.

Comment: @rajat_474 Please check Gemfile.lock for the wicked_pdf version?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78967/discussion-between-sufinsha-and-rajat-474).